# incomplete upload to ftp

Tags: c#, file-upload, ftp, upload, ftpwebrequest

Im using this [CodeProject](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/443588/Simple-Csharp-FTP-Class) to upload my files to my ftp server and it works well. This is a part of the code for uploading to server:

```
/* Upload File */
public void upload(string remoteFile, string localFile)
{
    try
    {
        /* Create an FTP Request */
        ftpRequest = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(host + "/" + remoteFile);
        /* Log in to the FTP Server with the User Name and Password Provided */
        ftpRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(user, pass);
        /* When in doubt, use these options */
        ftpRequest.UseBinary = true;
        ftpRequest.UsePassive = true;
        ftpRequest.KeepAlive = true;
        /* Specify the Type of FTP Request */
        ftpRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
        /* Establish Return Communication with the FTP Server */
        ftpStream = ftpRequest.GetRequestStream();
        /* Open a File Stream to Read the File for Upload */
        FileStream localFileStream = new FileStream(localFile, FileMode.Open);
        /* Buffer for the Downloaded Data */
        byte[] byteBuffer = new byte[bufferSize];
        int bytesSent = localFileStream.Read(byteBuffer, 0, bufferSize);
        /* Upload the File by Sending the Buffered Data Until the Transfer is Complete */
        try
        {
            while (bytesSent != 0)
            {
                ftpStream.Write(byteBuffer, 0, bytesSent);
                bytesSent = localFileStream.Read(byteBuffer, 0, bufferSize);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString()); }
        /* Resource Cleanup */
        localFileStream.Close();
        ftpStream.Close();
        ftpRequest = null;
    }
    catch (Exception ex) { Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString()); }
    return;
}
```

But most of the files will be incomplete in server. For example all my files are 1024KB but in server most of them are incomplete like 1019KB,1015KB,1023KB,...

Q: What is the reason of data loss during upload ? is it related to the code or its somthing else ?

Note: I've tested it with three ftp servers with fast and stable connection. OS of servers was WindowsServer2012R2 and local OS's was 7 and 8.1 and 10. firewall was off during test.

Comment: Your code looks correct. - Anyway, did you check if you write a correct number of bytes? Does the sum of all `bytesSent` match the expected file size? + What if you upload the file using simple `WebClient.UploadFile`? Would it upload correctly?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl sum of all `bytesSent` does not match the expected file size. says: 1048576byte to send and 1033667byte sent. going to try `WebClient.UploadFile`

Comment: How do you calculate "to send"?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl got the `localFile` size in byte. seems wrong! if it calculate bytetosend wrong every time then why its diffrent for same file on each try?

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand you question. Anyway how did you *"got the localFile size in byte"*. Show us! What is `localFileStream.Length`? + Did you try the `WebClient.UploadFile`?

Comment: Your code works perfectly for me.

Comment: What is your `bufferSize`?

Comment: `long size = localFileStream.Length` for size. it returns 1048576 . buffer size is 2048 and found [this for WebClient just now](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/FTP-Files-to-Server-Using-23d85d62).

Comment: Even with 2048, your code works for me. `WebClient` is trivial: `WebClient.UploadFile(host + "/" + remoteFile, localFile)`. Can you upload the file using any standalone FTP client?

Comment: Using a standalone FTP client is absolutely better, easier and accurate, but im making a low size console app and need this uploader inside my app

Comment: I understand that, I just wondered if it is server-side problem. I do not think there's anything wrong with your code.

Comment: Thank you @MartinPrikryl this is a Huge help. at least i got sure the problem is not server side and the code is correct, and i should look into my connection or ... , i will respond to this post when i solved this issue.

Comment: Used WebClient and got the same result (files are not uploaded correctly). Thanks to @MartinPrikryl im sure now the problem is my connection stability or InternetSecurity software limitation.

Comment: Why do you think so? You wrote yourself that sum of `bytesSent` does not match. And that data come from local file stream. It has nothing to do with the connection.

Comment: Did I understood right that if you add `totalBytes += bytesSent` at the end of the `while` loop, it does not match `localFileStream.Length`, right?

Comment: Again, that does not make sense. `totalBytes` calculates data **read** from a local file. I do not see how that can be influenced by anything on the network. Or are you saying that you get different `totalBytes`, when you completely skip the `ftpStream.Write(byteBuffer, 0, bytesSent);`?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl seems that worked accidentally 2 days ago. checked it again now it sends incomplete again. used [this](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/FTP-Files-to-Server-Using-23d85d62) written with `WebClient.UploadFile` and it send incomplete too. also `localFileStream.Length` always shows 1048576 and `totalBytes += bytesSent` shows 1046528 byte (2048byte diffrence as much as buffersize!) even with skipping `ftpStream.Write(byteBuffer, 0, bytesSent);`

Comment: Show us the code that you use to calculate the `totalBytes`, with excluded `ftpStream.Write`. Append it to your question.